# probability of misfiring sparkplugs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

a certain automobile engine has eight spark plugs, including two that are misfiring sparkplugs. If four plugs are pulled at random.  What is the probability that among those four , there are no misfiring plugs ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to check off a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $8$ plugs and we need to choose $4$ of them we have $8 \choose 4$- total number of combinations. The combinations, which do not include misfiring ones- $6 \choose 4$.

So we have: $$\frac{6\choose 4}{8 \choose 4}=\frac{3}{14} $$

Answer (score 2):

OK, the probability that the first sparkplug is OK is $\frac{6}{8}$ , the probability that the second is OK is $\frac{5}{7}$ (because the first one is "gone") Next one in line is $\frac{4}{6}$ and lastly $\frac{3}{5}$ Since all events have to happen, we multiply those outcomes: $\frac{3}{14}$. I initially misread the question and so I edited my original answer with the correct one provided by Brian

Comment: Isn´t the probability that the first sparkplug is OK equal to 6/8 ?

Comment: @imranfat please edit your answer.

Comment: @DanijelSubotic I want to delete my answer, because I misread the question and I believe my answer is wrong. The website won't allow me to delete.

Comment: @newtostat: The approach here is acceptable, but the numbers are wrong.  The product should be $\frac{6}{8} \times \frac{5}{7} \times \frac{4}{6} \times \frac{3}{5} = \frac{3}{14}$.  (imranfat's (ETA: original) answer would have been correct if *four* spark plugs were misfiring, instead of two.)

Comment: now I got it thanks